# Power BI Data Source

Tags: datasource, amazon-redshift, powerbi-embedded

I am in the process of integrating Power BI Embedded in our application and concerned about few things regarding to Data Source.

Our application is hosted in AWS and it would be better to connect with AWS RDS for our reports. From the Documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/power-bi-embedded/power-bi-embedded-connect-datasource), there are only 2 data sources supported. Also, Is there a possibility to connect to Amazon Redshift as a data source for Power BI Embedded reports?.

1) What is the best approach as we have our application in AWS and also with respect to cost and pricing?

2) What will be the performance impact between AWS Redshift and Azure Data Warehouse?

3) What are the pros and cons of using both the data sources?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hi, this is really multiple questions and some of them are way too broad for this site (e.g. compare the performance of Redshift and ADW). This isn't the place for those kind of discussions so you're unlikely to get any answers. If you want to ask a specific, answerable question (e.g. can Power BI use Redshift as a data source) please consider posting this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Hope not too late , with power BI you could connect and get data from various sources as well as from Amazon Redshift. From you Desktop app, simply click on Get data, and to make it quicker and easier use the search box to look for the data source needed then click connect to import the data needed into your work space.

[image]